# Web Site Javascript Requirement in app-inventor

Tags: javascript, cookies, app-inventor

I've hosted my PHP Mysql data in ByetHost.com 
When my App Inventor 2 App access data from it, it says enable javascript in my browser. I'm using the web component. How can I enable javascript in app inventor 2 and set request header for cookies with expiry. thanks.

Comment: You might want to follow [this tutorial](https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php). You also might be interested in the video tutorial [Connect App Inventor to MySQL Database](http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/05/connect-app-inventor-mysql-database/) by Derek Banas.

Comment: Many thanks!. My app is working using my own web server (Win7/ IIS/PHP) but NOT on the hosted one.

Comment: The desired results (all text)  shows when I used the webviewer component. Is there a simple way to copy the contents in the webviewer visual content to another control say a label? Thanks.